# Syntax error with async function definition inside a class

Tags: node.js, firebase, asynchronous, actions-on-google

I have a class with a few functions that I need to be async, but adding async in front of the function name gives me an error when compiling. (Testing with just one function atm)

```
class cataAPIService {

    async getRouteDetails(route) {
        var busID;
        for(var i = 0; i < catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses.length; i++) {
          if(catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses[i].name === route) {
            busID = catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses[i].id;
            console.log("Got bus id: " + busID);
          }
        }
        var deferred  = Promise.defer();
        try {
            const data = await axios.get("https://realtime.catabus.com/InfoPoint/rest/RouteDetails/Get/" + route);
            console.log(data)
            deferred.resolve(data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error in API call")
            deferred.reject(error)
        }
        return deferred.promise
}
```

Removing async it complies fine but I lose the functionality that I need. Am I making a silly mistake and missing it? Thanks

Picture of console error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Functions deploy to node 6 by default (you can see that in your console output). node 6 doesn't support async/await syntax.  If you want to use async/await, you have to either [deploy to node 8](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) (in beta), or use some sort of transpiled language like TypeScript.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know that. I am now deploying to node 8

Answer (score 1):

This is correct syntax. Async functions are fully supported since Node 8. Syntax error will only occur if older Node version is used. Node should be updated to newer version if possible.

The code uses [deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern) and doesn't require `async` function. It could be:

```
async getRouteDetails(route) {
    var busID;
    for(var i = 0; i < catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses.length; i++) {
      if(catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses[i].name === route) {
        busID = catabusRoutes.BUS_ROUTE_ID.buses[i].id;
        console.log("Got bus id: " + busID);
      }
    }
    return axios.get("https://realtime.catabus.com/InfoPoint/rest/RouteDetails/Get/" + route)
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error in API call");
        throw error;
    });
}
```

Comment: Fairly new to promises and still trying to understand the syntax behind it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Check your Node.js version.

**Async functions are not supported by Node versions older than version 7.6.**

You'll need to transpile your code (e.g. using Babel) to a version of JS that Node understands if you are using an older version.